# Laravel 5.1 how to get response from scheduler command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want get response from the command

my command like this

```
public function handle(){
    return 'something';
}
```

Kernel.php

```
$schedule->command('mycommand')
            ->cron('* * * * *');
$return_value = ?????;
//save $return_value to DB.
```

How can I get the command return,

I just want store the result to Database.

Comment: You should read the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan. It's all in there.

Comment: What is the "result" you want to store in the database?

Comment: The 'something' String which is return form the command

Comment: I think you can simply store the value in database before you return it since that should be equivelent

Comment: Thank, I just use cache to store it for temp